# Facebook like button for individual text in xml

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I have an XML file that stores the data of a list of 10 winners.

These winners will then be displayed in a html page and will each have a Facebook like button individually e.g

winner 1  [FB like button]
winner 2  [FB like button]
winner 3  [FB like button]
.
.
.

When someone clicks the FB like button say for 'winner 1' and if the person who clicked have not logged into FB, the prompt to login will pop up. When it's successful, an update will show in their profile that they have 'Liked a link'.

I have done all the above except **how do I separate each winner and make them unique when someone likes them**? Currently, it's the overall page. The list of winners listed will not be shown as their Facebook profile but instead just a text of their names.

I already have the FB meta tags from the open graph in the header. I just want it to display on the person's wall by using this meta tag:-

whereby xxx is according to the list of 10 winners.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a seperate webpage with different og:tags for each person.
You can do this with `http://example.com/overallPage?id=x` and set the tags according to the ID. Especially the `og:url` and `og:title` Tags should be set to a different value then.

It would be really easy to simply use `id=*name*` and set `og:title` to the name you passed.
For the Like-Tag, just set URL to the url with the id and each Like-button will have a different counter.

Comment: Ahh that's the problem, I don't want to create separate pages for each winner

Comment: As far as I know there is no other feasible way. You don't really create a new page, you just use some standard-PHP (or whatever you're using) to modify some data in the header. It should only be like 3 lines more than before...